# Query select multiple count from table 1 join table 2 in multiple condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some problem how to make query for multiple count with different condition from 1 table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM account_holder
INNER JOIN vehicle 
ON account_holder.`id`= vehicle.`accholder_id`
WHERE vehicle.`class_code`= 'BM' AND (vehicle.`roadtax_expired` > CURDATE()) 
AND (vehicle.`block_flag`='N') AND (vehicle.`is_blacklist`='N')
```

Scenario: I want to count class_code in table vehicle with different code. As example, my query just count code for BM, but how can I count others class_code in one query ?

Other different class_code: BL, CA, CE...

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (That query won't run on both.)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Comment: I'm using mysql

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `GROUP BY` clause to calculate each `class_code`.

```
SELECT vehicle.`class_code`, COUNT(*) 
FROM account_holder
     INNER JOIN vehicle 
        ON account_holder.`id`= vehicle.`accholder_id`
WHERE (vehicle.`roadtax_expired` > CURDATE()) 
       AND (vehicle.`block_flag`='N') 
       AND (vehicle.`is_blacklist`='N')
GROUP BY vehicle.`class_code`
```

Comment: It's working, but how can i select several class_code because some of the code it might not being used in query. At now, how can the other class_code , like e.g class_code 'BG' that i dont even want to being listed in query ?

Comment: add a condition in the `WHERE` clause. `AND (vehicle.block_flag='N') AND (vehicle.is_blacklist='N') AND vehicle.class_code NOT IN ('BG','XX', 'YY')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with group by,

```
SELECT COUNT(vehicle.`class_code`) as class_code count FROM  account_holder
INNER JOIN vehicle 
ON account_holder.`id`= vehicle.`accholder_id`
WHERE (vehicle.`roadtax_expired` > CURDATE()) 
AND (vehicle.`block_flag`='N') AND (vehicle.`is_blacklist`='N') group   by vehicle.`class_code`
```